# proof that a function plus a lower growth function is theta the first function.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

my assignment is to (dis)prove the following

$ f(n)+o(f(n))=\Theta(f(n)) $

for example:

$ \forall n \geq n', n + \log(n) = c \cdot n $

so far I have:

$ \forall n \geq n', f(n) = o(g(n)) \leftrightarrow f(n) < c \cdot g(n) $ (definition of little-o)

$ \forall n \geq n', f(n) = \Theta(g(n)) \leftrightarrow f(n) = c \cdot g(n) $ (definition of big-$ \Theta $)

Given $ g(n)=o(f(n)) $:

$ f(n)+o(f(n))=f(n)+g(n) $

$ f(n)=c \cdot f(n) $

$ g(n)<c \cdot f(n) $

I feel like I'm going in circles... any suggestions?

Comment: $n + \log(n) = c*n$ is not true for any $c$ if $n$ varies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $g(n)$ is $o(f(n))$, and let $h(n)=f(n)+g(n)$; you want to prove that $h(n)$ is $\Theta(f(n))$.

To show that $f(n)$ is $\Theta(h(n))$, you must show that there are positive constants $C_1,C_2$, and $n_0$ such that $C_1|f(n)|\le|h(n)|\le C_2|f(n)|$ for all $n\ge n_0$.

> **Note:** My $n_0$ corresponds to your $n'$. Note that in your post you have the inequalities involving $n$ and $n'$ backwards: you want something to be true for all $n$ **from some point on**, not just for all $n$ **up to some point**. Your definitions of $o$ and $\Theta$ are seriously off in other respects as well; you should check them against your text or [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).

Unpacking $h$, we want $C_1|f(n)|\le|f(x)+g(x)|\le C_2|f(n)|$ for all $n\ge n_0$. Since $g(n)$ is $o(f(n))$, we know that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n_\epsilon$ such that $|g(n)|<\epsilon|f(n)|$ whenever $n\ge n_\epsilon$. Take $\epsilon=\frac12$, and let $n_0=n_{1/2}$. Then whenever $n\ge n_0$ we have $|g(n)|\le\frac12|f(n)|$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\frac12|f(n)|&\le|f(n)|-|g(n)|\\
&\le|f(x)+g(x)|\\
&\le|f(n)|+|g(n)|\\
&\le\frac32|f(n)|\,,
\end{align*}$$

and we see that $C_1=\frac12$ and $C_2=\frac32$ do the trick with this value of $n_0$.

Comment: fixed the inequalities, thanks.

Comment: After taking $\epsilon=1/2$, $| g(n) | < \frac{1}{2} | f(n) |$ from definition of little-oh. But how did the equality part come?

Comment: @SPRajagopal: At the beginning of the displayed line? It must have been a typo on my part. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Actually, I meant this part: "Since g(n) is o(f(n)), we know that for each ϵ>0 there is an $n_{\epsilon}$ such that |g(n)|<ϵ|f(n)| whenever n≥nϵ. Take ϵ=0.5, and let $n_0=n_{1/2}$. Then whenever n≥n0 we have $|g(n)| \leq \frac{1}{2}|f(n)|$". The last $|g(n)| \leq \frac{1}{2}|f(n)|$ should just be $|g(n)|< \frac{1}{2}|f(n)|$? Because small-oh only has inequality no equality?

Comment: @SPRajagopal: If $a<b$, then it’s certainly also true that $a\le b$.

Comment: Okay that seems so simple but hard to wrap my head around. Surely $a<b$ is a stronger constraint than $a \leq b$? What I mean is $a<b$ covers a set $A$, $a \leq b$ covers a set $B$, then $A \subset B$?

Comment: @SPRajagopal: $a<b$ is in general a stronger constraint than $a\le b$; that is precisely why we know that if $a<b$, then certainly $a\le b$. And in this case all that I needed was the fact that $a\le b$. (Actually, in this setting there’s another reason that it doesn’t matter. If for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n_\epsilon$ such that $|g(n)|\le\epsilon|f(n)|$ whenever $n\ge n_\epsilon$, then for each $\epsilon>0$ there is also an $m_\epsilon$ such that $|g(n)|<|f(n)|$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$ and *vice versa*. You should try to prove this basic fact for yourself.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116134/discussion-between-sprajagopal-and-brian-m-scott).

Answer (score 2):

Those are not [correct statements of the notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).  Try something like

- $f(n) \in o(g(n))$ when  $|f(n)| \lt c|g(n)|$ for all $c\gt 0$ and for all $n \gt n_0$ for some $n_0$
- $f(n) \in \Theta(g(n))$ when  $k_1|g(n)| \lt |f(n)| \lt k_2|g(n)|$ for some $k_1,k_2 \gt 0$ and for all $n \gt n_0$ for some $n_0$

Instead, you can show that  $\frac12 \left|f(n)\right| \le \left|f(n)+o(f(n))\right| \le \frac32 \left|f(n)\right|$ for all sufficiently large $n$, i.e. when $\left|o(f(n))\right| \lt \frac12 \left|f(n)\right|$, and so  $f(n)+o(f(n)) \in \Theta (f(n))$.

Comment: just using the notation from http://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_To_Algorithms.html?id=NLngYyWFl_YC, but I'll check out the wiki also.

Comment: Sometimes definitions are slightly careless about absolute values. Your authors are not careless. They make the explicit assumption that all the functions they mention are asymptotically non-negative.

Comment: If it's good enough for Hardy and de Bruijn, it's good enough for me. To me, using "$\in$" instead of "=" when doing O work is needless formalism.